# Acera M360 upgrade

Tags: shimano, derailleur-rear

My 7-speed Shimano Acera M360 rear derailleur fell apart and I now need to replace it.

I could simply just buy the same but honestly I never liked it very much and would appreciate something with a more precise shifting also during heavy uphill efforts. My shifters are ST-EF65s and I do not want to change them or the bowden or any other parts than the rear derailleur. Can you please advise which components might be compatible with a slightly better quality and not very expensively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any 7/8/9 Speed derailleur with enough capacity (essentially cage length) will work.

Shifting quality is about the system, not a single component. Replacing just the derailleur, even with the very best, will make little difference. However reasonable quality components are often available at discount prices cheaper than low spec components, so shop around for the best quality derailleur that fits you price point, but see below....  While other brands (SRAM and Microshift) make compatible components, its  probably best to stay with  with Shimano.

Without knowing more about the bike, here is the order I would be looking at things to improve shifting.

New, quality cables (inner and outer) would be my likely make more difference than the shifter.  Unless the existing cables are 'as new' these would be my first thing to change and would always go with a new derailleur.

Chain and cassette - these wear out and need replacing occasionally anyway.  If worn, they will cause bad shifting.

Shifter - while the feel of shifting is affected by having a quality shifter, its probably at the bottom of the list of things that cause poor shifting.

With all the above done, tuning can make or  break the setup. Be prepared to spend time getting it right.